# Get Names from a table, using LINQ (EF) with a specific suffix

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I've got a project in ASP.NET MVC.
I need to connect a database, and pull from them all the clients with the suffix `'r'`. I tried:

```
public class MyDBRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<MyClient> GetNamesBySuffix(char symbol)
    {
        List<MyClient> myClients = new List<MyClient>();

        using (MyDBEntities m = new MyDBEntities())
        {
            List<Client> Clients = new List<Client>();
            Clients = m.Clients.Where(c => c.name[c.name.Length-1] == symbol).ToList();
            foreach (Client client in Clients)
            {
                MyClient newClient = new MyClient() { Name = client.name };
                myClients.Add(newClient);
            }
            return myClients;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting `System.NotSupportedException`, I cant use index `(c.name[c.name.Length-1])` in the sql obviously..
ty for the helpers!

Comment: have you tried : `m.Clients.Where(c => c.name.EndsWith("r");` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the Below code which is used EndsWith to find the data based on the last character.

```
public class MyDBRepository
{
  public IEnumerable<MyClient> GetNamesBySuffix(char symbol)
  {
    List<MyClient> myClients = new List<MyClient>();

    using (MyDBEntities m = new MyDBEntities())
    {
      myClients = m.Clients.Where(c => c.name.Trim().EndsWith(symbol+""))
                           .Select(c=>new MyClient {name=c.name})
                           .ToList();           
      return myClients;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ty! really helpful!

Comment: what?, should i do something?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Clients = m.Clients.Where(c => c.name.EndsWith(symbol.ToString())).ToList();
```